Understanding Uniqueness of SDEs
I am a little confused about SDEs and their unique solutions.
Let's say I write an SDE $dX_t = A_t dt + B_t dW_t$. Is it not the case that I can write the solution $X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t A_s ds + \int_0^t B_s dW_s$ as a solution subject to conditions like $\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[B_s^2] < \infty$? This doesn't seem to require any lipschitz/bounded derivative type condition to show uniqueness or existence right? The first integral can be shown to exist and the second integral exists and is unique as an $L^2$ limit. It almost seems a tautology, I guess.
When one writes $X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t A_s ds + \int_0^t B_sdW_s$ is that an existence statement or a uniqueness statement or both? I guess I probably have a foundational misunderstanding of what SDEs are and what their solutions are.

No one said that the Lipschitz condtion is necessary to have existence and uniqueness. As we know: it is sufficient. Secondly, when your $A,B$ are not functions of $X$ it is a bit of an exaggeration to call that an SDE. When they are functions of $X$ then you have not solved it by just expressing $dX$ in integral form.

@KurtG. $A_t$ and $B_t$ are general stochastic processes possibly with continuous paths, that are adapted to the desired filtration. There is no need for them to be a function of $X_t$ is there, if so it would be a diffusion.

That is totally fine with me. Then $X_t=X_0+\int_0^tA_s,ds+\int_0^tB_s,dW_s$ is uniquely defined whenever those integrals are defined. No need to look up anything about SDEs. Just stochastic integrals. Put it this way: would you call $y'=f(x)$ an ODE? I don't. Its "solution" is $y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^xf(u),du,.$

That's a flawed example. There is no equivalent of $(y')^3 + 4y'' + 6y = 7x^3 + 4$ in SDEs. SDEs always have the given form, while ode's do not have to. Your claim that $X_t$ is uniquely defined is wrong I believe.

Very interesting. Awaiting further details.

(local) Lipschitz conditions are enough to guarantee existence and uniqueness of a strong solution for SDEs of the very general form $dX_t = \mu(t, X_.) dt +\sigma(t, X_.) dB_t$, where the drifts and diffusion coefficients are previsible path functionals, i.e. depend on the path of $X$ up to time $t$. This is Theorem 11.2, p.128 of Rogers and Williams Volume 2. I am not aware of any general conditions for arbitrary previsible/adapted processes for coefficients.

In fact, if $dX_t=A_tdt + B_tdW_t$ and $dY_t=C_t dt + D_td\tilde{W}_t$ such that $A_t=C_t$ a.s. for all $t$ and $B_tB_t^T = D_tD_t^T$ a.s. for all $t$, then the infinitesimal generators of the two processes are identical, and so $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are equal in distribution but they differ pathwise--i.e. the stochastic integral equation is not unique. Right?
